# Highcharts send a lot of request when "enablePolling: true", with "googleSpreadsheetKey"

Tags: javascript

I have set the dataRefreshRate for 20s, but it doesn't work, it send alot of request to server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrL8Y.png)

Comment: It doesnt look like their example works either https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/live-data

Answer (score 0):

After an hour finding the issue, finally I 've solve it. 
The unit of dataRefreshrate when we load data from CSV is different from loading from googleSpreadsheetKey, CSV use the unit Second while googleSpreadsheetKey use the unit MiliSecond. So, If the value in CSV = 10, mean in googleSpreadsheetKey = 10000